# How do I get a web view in a list view in Blackberry Cascades, QML & C++, QT

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml, blackberry-10

I am trying to get a list of images from the internet to show up in a list view in QML.  I have code that looks like this:

```
ListView {

    objectName: "imageListView"

    listItemComponents: [

        ListItemComponent {

            type: "item"

            Container {
                WebView {
                     url: ListItemData.imageSource
                }    
            }                           
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is this just causes the following error: "Unable to assign [undefined] to QUrl url"

I know the ListItemData.imageSource contains the correct data, because I tested it using, Label { text: ListItemData.imageSource }, in place of the WebView, and it showed all the image urls that are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so I found another solution.  I upgraded from the Beta 2 SDK to the Beta 3 SDK.  Then I simply did something like this:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <bb/cascades/Image>

class MyImageClass : public QObject, public bb::cascades::Image
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bb::cascades::Image image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged FINAL)

    //...
    bb::cascades::Image image_;
public:
    //...
    bb::cascades::Image image() const {return image_;}

    void setImage(bb::cascades::Image image {
         image_ = image;
         emit imageChanged();
    }

signals:
    //...
    void imageSourceChanged();
}
```

Then when inserting an image into the list, I simply used:

```
groupDataModel_.insert(myImageObject);
```

and in my qml I have:

```
ListView {
    id: imageListView
objectName: "ImageListView"         

    listItemComponents: [
    ListItemComponent {
        type: "item"

        Container {
            id: imagesRoot
            objectName: "ImagesRoot"

                ImageView {
                image: ListItemData.image
            }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use ImageView only even if you are loading images from internet.

First of all, make a network request using QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager, and QNetworkReply classes & on getting reply load that QByteArray in ImageView.

```
QNetworkAccessManager* netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
if (netManager) {

QUrl url(ImageUrl);
QNetworkRequest networkRequest(url);
QNetworkReply* networkReply = netManager->get(networkRequest);
connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReply()));
}
```

& in onReply() slot you can load image like this:

```
void App::onReply(QNetworkReply* reply) {
if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    qDebug() << "Image not available or any error";
    return;
}

Image image = Image(reply->readAll());
imageView->setImage(image);

}
```

Do note that if the image is too large, you may have to ImageData class & its method to load image in cascade ImageView. It won't load image directly by using setImage method. & to make this work with ListView, you have to create your own CustomItem & ListItemProvider & also have to override update item method of that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou, but it seems ListItemProvider is missing from the cascades folder, now I am trying to find where I can download that missing class from the internet, if anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Well you have to extend ListItemProvider class & create your own custom provider for that in C++

Comment: Yes, thankyou, I understand, but when I try to include ListItemProvider with #include <bb/cascades/ListItemProvider>, and then scroll over that #include statement with my mouse, it says, "Unresolved inclusion", and it's underlined in yellow, and when I try to compile, there is an error message saying that that ListItemProvider file does not exist.

Comment: What OS are you working on? ListItemProvider was previously named as ListItemManager in BB 10.0.6 (Beta 2 SDK). Now on its named as ListItemProvider in BB 10.0.9 (Beta 3 SDK).

Comment: Thankyou, but when I download the images, I just get: '"Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã' from reply->readAll()

Comment: Its fine. Its in QByteArray form that's why it shows like that. Just pass it in constructor of Image's object. It should work. If it doesn't, Image would be too large to fit in ImageView. Max dimensions of an image which can be handled by cascade ImageView is 2048. So you may have to use ImageData class to replicate large image into cascade ImageView.

Comment: Okay, try loading image from this url http://cdn3.berryreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/blackberry-10-dev-alpha.jpg It works for me with this url without any use of ImageData class